# How should I add this function in my JS

Tags: javascript

```js
function criar() {
    
}, 20000);
```

I need to add this function inside the JS code as it should be?

```js
xz = Math['flo]() * 9999) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, create a function for that first:

```
const xz = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 1);
```

and then you can use it like:

```
$['post']('/api/user/avatars', {
    uniqueId: 'hhbr-0f6b016e79824439db28907b51493876',
    name: 'SCORP_' + xz()   // just call the function here again
})
```

DEMO:

```
function criar() {
  const xz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 1);
  $['post']('/api/user/avatars', {
    uniqueId: 'hhbr-0f6b016e79824439db28907b51493876',
    name: 'SCORP_' + xz
  })
}
setInterval(function() {
  criar()
}, 20000);
```

Comment: I do not understand much, you could join the function for me, please.

Comment: I have added a demo. Check it out.

Comment: Yes it was great the problem is that this function could be inside the create function so it could repeat without having to do manual?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code. See if that work for you.

Comment: I also need to merge the API to do the verification
$['post']('/api/user/avatars', {
    uniqueId: 'hhbr-0f6b016e79824439db28907b51493876',
    name: 'SCORP_' + xz()   // just call the function here again
})

Comment: Can you do this for me, please?

Comment: Just use `name: 'SCORP_' + xz` there and it will work fine

Comment: Yes I did this is test, it went wrong you can modify it for me if you do not ask too much.

Comment: gave as "undefined"

Comment: In normal the code comes like this
paste2.org/O5F87Vh0

Comment: so I just wanted to add the "xz" function inside the create function without changing the API

Comment: thank you for helping me to have patience, sorry if I could not explain it better so being faster is that I do not understand much. I just thank you!